# Fragmentation of indexes with small a database

Tags: sql-server, fragmentation

I'm trying to figure out whether its worth defragging a 2GB mssql database. 
indexs are above 70% fragmented but queries don't appear to be talking too along.

That being said I am having a delay when requesting to play multiple voice files and havent figured out yet if this because of a delay when our software requests the path of the .wav from the Database, or if its down to some other factor

[image]

Comment: ONLY If index has `page_count >1500` then it makes sense to rebuild or reorganize it. For such a small database there would just be few indexes

Comment: Generally, no: [Why Defragmenting Your Indexes Isn’t Helping](https://groupby.org/conference-session-abstracts/why-defragmenting-your-indexes-isnt-helping/).

Comment: Also, the database may be memory resident if you have adequate memory and not much else on the server. Fragmentation isn't a concern in that case. I suggest you mine the `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` and/or `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` DMVs to see how long queries are actually running, and perhaps a trace too.

Comment: Does it take a long time to start playing the file, or does it take along time for the system run the query that gets the file to play?